# SHELL: sub arguments?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I came across this shell command:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -b:a 32k video.mp3
```

It seems to be that it has an option "`a:`", but don't know how to give as "`b:a`".
doesn't "`b:a`"  mean an option `-b`, which takes in an argument,  and an option "a" with no arguments? Can anyone show me how to replicate `-b:a` 32k?

Comment: It's FFmpeg-specific argument format. You specify the bitrate of the audio stream with `-b:a`, and that of the video stream with `-b:v`.

Comment: Yes my question is how do I define such an option with `while optargs "" option; do`?

Comment: That's not possible with simple Bash script and stock utilities. You have to write your own logic to parse this kind of non-standard syntaxes.

Comment: Emphasis: It's not any kind of standard syntax. FFmpeg invented their own, as well as their parsing logic.

Comment: The standard convention is ambiguous: without knowing exactly how the options are defined, `-b:a` could be synonymous with `-b -: -a`, or `-b :a`. (It's never a single option with `b:a` as its name, as `ffmpeg` interprets its.)

Comment: I wouldn't use `optargs` for this task. Just loop over the arguments and implement your own logic.